# Changing wordpress plugin functionality

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

I am attempting to change the code within a widget, within a plugin.

I do not want to change the plugin directly, and was wondering if I could just duplicate the code and place somewhere else within the theme and change it there?

It's a rather large plugin and I just want to duplicate/amend one of it's widgets.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's a little more involved than I though it might be. I found this helpful article on best practices: https://iandunn.name/the-right-way-to-customize-a-wordpress-plugin/